# Action Sheets then Alert Box Delete Confirmation Issue (iOS)

Tags: ios, design, confirmation, delete

This is regarding the user experience issue in iOS, iPhone.

User comes to the first screen, which is the action sheet with a more button on a previous page. There is only one option which is delete message.

When user tap on the delete message button, user will be prompt a delete confirmation alert box.

These 2 seems redundant, how to solve this issue while still having the delete confirmation?
The more button must remain. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you still need the delete confirmation then you need redundancy. Why do you call redundancy issue? :)

I don't know if my solution fits good with iOS guidelines but you can do the following - after user tap <kbd>Delete Message</kbd> change its name to <kbd>Undelete Message</kbd> and change name of <kbd>Cancel</kbd> to <kbd>Delete Forever</kbd>.

If user press <kbd>Undelete Message</kbd> change tap names back and stay at current screen. If user press <kbd>Delete Forever</kbd> make deletion and bring him back to previous screen.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your solution but I do agree that the redundancy is a necessity. Where I work we call it a "sanity check" - a little follow up on any destructive action that, hopefully, catches most accidental clicks.